# How to set equal width with percentages % in html

Tags: html, css, css-float

Note:
Before I posted my question I have searched this site to get answers, but I couldn't find any solution which allows me to set equal margin in percentages value.

The following codes are not scaling to full 25% of it wight:

Please see the sample HTML code below:

```
<style>

#Wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:70%;
}

#MainLogo{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#LeftSide{
    width:25%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color:#90F;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}

#FloatLeft {
    float:left;
}

#One{
    width:25%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}

#Two{
    width:25%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#F00;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;

}

#Three{
    width:25%;
    height:295px;
    background-color:#F00;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    }

#Four{
    width:25%;
    height:295px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}


#RightSide{
    width:25%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color:#00F;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#MainFooter{
width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    clear:both;
}

</style>


<body>

<div id="Wrapper">

<header id="MainLogo">
Logo Goes here!!
</header>

<aside id="LeftSide">
Left side goes here
</aside>

<div id="FloatLeft">

<aside id="One">
One Goes Here!!
</aside>

<aside id="Two">
Two aside goes here!!
</aside>

<aside id="Three">
Three aside goes here!!
</aside>

<aside id="Four">
Four aside goes here!!
</aside>
</div> 

<aside id="RightSide">
Right side goes here
</aside>

<footer id="MainFooter">
Main Footer Goes here!!
</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because of things such as `padding` and `margin`. You are going to need to use the `box-sizing` property to get the effect you want.

First, you should remove the padding and margin for everything, then set the `box-sizing` property to `border-box`. This will ensure that no matter how much `padding` or `margin` you have, it will always stay at the `height`, and `width` you specify.

Here is a sample usage

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing-border-box;
}
```

The `box-sizing` property isn't fully supported yet, so you will need to use vendor specific properties

Comment: @user2344984 Did you try my solution?

Comment: Hi I am trying the box-sizing:border-box solution you have provided. but for some reason it not working. I will continue to practice as I am new to webdesign and HTML.

Comment: Did you use the vendor prefixes? Add your HTML and a fiddle into your question if you want more help

Comment: Hi, yes i did use  vendor prefixes but I couldn't get it to work. all the html code is OK except for #one #Two #Three and #Four. Please can you show me an example.

Comment: I need your HTML, along with a fiddle

Comment: Hi Cody, I have solve the problem, all i did is just added width:50%. #FloatLeft {
float:left;
width:50%;
 
}